# Google Cloud Dataflow to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-beam

[image] Above reference architecture indicates the existence of Cloud Storage sink from Cloud Dataflow, however the Beam API which seems to be the current default Dataflow API has no Cloud Storage I/O connector listed.

[image]

Can anyone help clarify if there is one that exists, if not what is the alternative to bring data from Dataflow to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beam does support writing/reading from GCS. You simply use the `TextIO` classes.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.2.0-incubating/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html

> To read a PCollection from one or more text files, use TextIO.Read. You can instantiate a transform using TextIO.Read.from(String) to specify the path of the file(s) to read from (e.g., a local filename or filename pattern if running locally, or a **Google Cloud Storage filename or filename pattern of the form "gs:///"**).

Answer (score 1):

You can use TextIO, AvroIO or any other connector that reads from/writes to files to interact with GCS. Beam identifies any file path that starts with "gs://" to be for GCS. Beam does this using the pluggable FileSystem [1] interface.

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/storage/GcsFileSystem.java

Comment: The above listed comment is dead, do you have another link?

Comment: I guess this is the current working link for that file: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/google-cloud-platform-core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/storage/GcsFileSystem.java